# How to make a custom ToolbarControl Item in ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine

I would like to create a custom toolbar item in `ArcEngine`.

I add items like this

```
((AxToolbarControl)toolbarControl).AddItem( myCustomItem )
```

I need to know how to create a custom item in ArcEngine 10.  I'm using C# and VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the ArcGIS project you're creating into Visual Studio 2010. Right-click your project (not your solution) in the Solution Exlorer and select "Add," and then select "New Item...".

Click the arrow next to ArcGIS in the list on the left or the Add New Item dialog box and then click on Extending ArcObjects. Select the item you want to create (Base Tool, in this case), and then click Add. Choose the "MapControl or PageLayoutControl" item in the list on the ArcGIS New Item Wizard Options dialog box (since you're using Engine).

You can then alter the command created however you see fit.

See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Using_item_templates_to_extend_ArcObjects/00010000010q000000/) for further information.